# How to Verify Reserved IP with Powershell

Tags: powershell, networking, scripting, powershell-3.0, dhcp

I am working on a little powershell 3.0 GWMI script that pulls computer information for use in an enterprise environment (ip, mac address, etc).

I'm trying to go through the WMI properties for `NetworkAdapterConfiguration` to see if there is a way to check for a reserved IP vs. a dynamically assigned one.

Would anyone have advice on how to pull this from WMI or elsewhere? Does (preferred) always indicate that an IP is reserved on the network?

I'm finding a lot of information for powershell and Azure but not a ton for figuring this out on a local box.

Comment: `(Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration).DHCPEnabled`

Comment: You would need to check on the DHCP server to see if the address is reserved or dynamic. A host cannot know if a DHCP-assigned address was reserved on the DHCP server, or if the address was simply assigned from the dynamic scope.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Ron Maupin noted, Host computers will only know whether they were assigned an addressed from the DHCP, not if there was a reservation. But they will report which DHCP server they received their address from. So you can query that server (assuming you have read permissions).

Here is a script that after retrieving the information from a computer over WMI will check with the DHCP server if a reservation exists.

```
$ComputerName = "ExampleComputer"
$NetAdapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -ComputerName $ComputerName | ? {$_.DHCPEnabled -eq $True -and $null -ne $_.IPAddress}
If ($NetAdapters) {
    Foreach ($Adapter in $NetAdapters) {
        foreach ($IP in $Adapter.IPAddress) {
            $Reservation = Get-DhcpServerv4Reservation -ScopeId $IP -ComputerName $Adapter.DHCPServer | ? {$_.ScopeId -eq $_.IPAddress}
            If ($Reservation) {
                Write-Output "$IP is reserved on $($Adapter.DHCPServer)."
            } Else {
                Write-Output "$IP does not have a reservation."
            }
        }
    }
} Else {
    Write-Output "No DHCP Enabled NetAdapters with IPAddresses exist on host, likely Static"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the above script provided by BenH I was able to cobble together a script that worked across my fleet of AWS servers from SSM using the AWS-RunPowerShellScript run document which would give me a fail status if any of my instances weren't configured for DHCP. We had a few lingering out there which were using our DHCP Options Set in our VCP and this helped uncover them. Thanks!

```
$NetAdapters = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | ? {$_.DHCPEnabled -eq $True -and $null -ne $_.IPAddress} | Select Description
If ($NetAdapters) {
    Foreach ($Adapter in $NetAdapters.Description) {
        Write-Output "DHCP is enabled on $Adapter"
        exit 0
    }
} Else {
    Write-Output "DHCP is not enabled on any adapters on host, likely Static"
    exit 1
}
```